# Что делать если не билдится или не компилируется проект Cmake?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Здесь я напишу все решения проблемы с Cmake.

1. Обязательно проверьте, что имя пользователя Windows записано на английском. Возможно именно это является основной проблемой в создании проекта Cmake. Если имя все же на русском, выполните всё по инструкции с этого сайта - https://mywebpc.ru/windows/pereimenovat-papku-polzovatelya/
2. Настройте свой проект командой cmake . из папки вашего проекта. Если данная программа не сработает, значит ваш cmake не может выбрать нужный генератор. Для этого используем данную опцию, в случае с g++ -G "MinGW Makefiles" Команда будет выглядеть так cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"
3. После настройки проекта, используйте команду cmake --build . ваш проект забилдится и вы сможет его запустить.
4. Команда для запуска - ./"Название вашего проекта в CmakeLists.txt"

Поздравляю мы создали проект и скомпилировали его, пользуйтесь!

Действуйте по инструкции и все получится.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6300/%d0%90%d0%ba%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-so-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: Спорные советы, которые к тому же не решают все проблемы.